# Character splitted while printing Arabic font text in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, split, arabic

I'm facing very peculiar issue. While printing work document having Arabic text in it, to a PDF; the Arabic text is split (originally it was ) and not coming as connected. its being spit after every character and printing something else.
Have used itext.jar for PDF generator in which all most all the text is split in separate character. Also used word's save as option, where only some of the characters are split while others are intact.

Please Help.

[image: Original & Converted Text]

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using Arial font in Word.
I think your issue is missing Glyph: `ـ` which is (\u0640) in font.
To resolve that you might use different base font or ship font file with PDF.

ship font to PDF:

```
BaseFont baseFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont("~/Content/fonts/ARIALN.ttf", BaseFont.CP1256,false, 10).getBaseFont();
```

Use different font:

```
BaseFont baseFont1 = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, "Cp1256", false);
```

Alternatively .. You can get rid of this character. that would the issue as well.